# How to separate tds and getting the n-th td in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to learn web scraping right now and I came across a problem with scraping this data:

```
<td align="left"><a href="/wiki/bob" title="bob">bob</a></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
```

I want to skip the first td align="left" because it doesn't have a title and I want to put the titles from the ones that that do have them with the 3rd td in a list of tuples (ex. [(bob, 3)...(name, value)]).

I've seen answers to getting the n-th row using soup.findAll() and a slice but how would I get specific tds? All suggestions would be useful and will help further my webscraping journey. Thanks!

Comment: If you know CSS selectors , this may be of some help: 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as the find_all tr, you would just do `find_all('td')`. The find_all returns a list and you'd want the 1st and forth items:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td align="left"><a href="/wiki/bob" title="bob">bob</a></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

thirdTD = (soup.find_all('td')[0].text, soup.find_all('td')[3].text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (thirdTD)
('bob', '3')
```